# Doubts regarding tricks to factor polynomials

Tags: polynomials, roots, factoring

I was reading a wiki page on brilliant.org titled Factoring by Substitution. I have a few questions regarding one of the solved examples given there

The question says: Solve for all the roots of the following polynomial
$$x^4-5ix^3+19x^2-125ix-150$$
Let the above polynomial be represented by $p(x)$. After making the substitution $a=ix$ and some grouping, the following result is stated
$$p(x)=(a^3-19a+30)(a-5)$$
Then the author states: "Using some logic, since there's a gap in powers ($a^3$ followed by $a$), there should be a difference of squares. By remainder theorem, since 5 is a solution, we can check -5."

Firstly, I don't understand why a gap in powers implies the existence of a difference in squares. Could anyone please explain this with some examples?

Secondly, how does the remainder theorem come into picture here? Even if it is applicable..the gap in powers is present in the first term, and 5 is not a factor of the first expression in the product..

On the whole... I don't understand the entire statement that is made which I've included in double quotations(" ") above...Could anyone please help me with this?

Link to the wiki page: https://brilliant.org/wiki/factor-polynomials-by-substitution/?subtopic=polynomials&chapter=polynomial-factoring

Thanks for any answers!!

Comment: Check please coefficients of the polynomial. Maybe it means $x^4-5x^3+19x^2-125x-150$ or $x^4-5ix^3+19x^2-125ix-150$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! I missed the $i$ in the 4th term! I have edited my question

Comment: Your polynomial directly factors as $ (x^2 - 6 - 5ix)(x^2 + 25)$. This seems more direct, without any tricks. Of course $x^2+25=(x+5i)(x-5i)$ and so on.

Comment: But how do we arrive at that?...and also I'm specifically trying to understand the statement made by the author..

Comment: I just computed $(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$ and compared coefficients. Very easy. No tricks.

Comment: I see no reason why a gap in powers leads to any conclusion about a difference of two squares. If such a conclusion was valid, we could say the same thing about $a^3-19a+18$, but (as can be verified) this factors as $(a-1)(a^2+a-18)$, which has no such difference of two squares property.

Comment: Oh..okay...Yea..comparing coefficients does look a lot simpler

Comment: Perhaps "gaps of powers" here just refers to even or odd exponent of $x$, which plays a role if you substitute $a=xi$.

Answer (score 1):

For the polynomial $a^3-19a+30$ it means the following reasoning.

Let $t$ be a root of the polynomial.

Thus, there is a factor $a-t$, but since the coefficient before $a^2$ is equal to $0$, we need to get a difference of squares $a^2-t^2$:
$$a^3-19a+30=a^3-ta^2+ta^2-t^2a+t^2a-19a+30=$$
$$=a^2(a-t)+ta(a-t)+t^2a-19a+30=$$
$$=a(a-t)(a+t)+t^2a-19a+30=a(a^2-t^2)+t^2a-19a+30.$$

For $x^4-5ix^3+19x^2-125ix-150$ by your hint we obtain:

let $x=ai$.

Thus, $$x^4-5ix^3+19x^2-125ix-150=a^4-5a^3-19a^2+125a-150.$$
Now, easy to see that $5$ and $-5$ are roots.

Thus, we have a factor $a^2-25$ and 
$$a^4-5a^3-19a^2+125a-150=a^4-25a^2-5a^3+125a+6a^2-150=$$
$$=(a^2-25)(a^2-5a+6)=(a-5)(a+5)(a-2)(a-3)=$$
$$=(ai-2i)(ai-3i)(ai+5i)(ai-5i)=$$
$$=(x-2i)(x-3i)(x+5i)(x-5i).$$

Comment: Do you know anything about the gap in powers which was mentioned?

Comment: @binarybitarray I added something. See now.